# Missing header file

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ programming and trying to add a library (Yepp) to my cpp file.

I am trying to compile and it says it cannot find a header file from the external library. The external library, yeppp, has a .so file which I placed in a lib folder in the root directory.

I am building with the following command:

```
clang++ -O3 test.cpp -o test -L lib/ -lyeppp
```

Here's the error:

```
test.cpp:7:10: fatal error: 'yepCore.h' file not found
#include <yepCore.h>
```

Comment: add something like `-I/path/to/yeppp/includes` to your `clang++` invocation

Comment: You told the linker where to find files to link with -L.  You didn't tell the compiler where to find .h files with -I.

Comment: Ah ok. I assumed linking .so file includes the header files. It is now fixed. Feel free to add it as an answer.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? I'm a C++ newbie and now won't post on here anymore.

Comment: @jap it seems obvious to many users, which think it is the nth question of this type. But searching on SO for "How to include header files in clang search path" doesnt give results which will be clear for a beginner. So I believe the downvotes are not justified.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler where to find the header file. Use the `-I` option.